# Javascript - ScrollToFixed in dynamically div id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am trying to make scroll follow with `ScrollToFixed.js`

This is my view:

```
<ul id="summary1" class="summary">
                    <li class="caption">Summary 1</li>
                    <li class="contents">
                        <p>There are three floating summaries on the right of this page.  They are anchored to their respective sections.</p>

                        <p>Once a summary reaches the bottom of the header above, it will stop there until the next section summary arrives.  Then, it will continue up the page.</p>

                        <p>The last summary will get pushed up the page by the footer once it undocks to reveal the content below it.</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>

<ul id="summary3" class="summary">
                        <li class="caption">Summary 3</li>
                        <li class="contents">
                            <p>There are three floating summaries on the right of this page.  They are anchored to their respective sections.</p>

                            <p>Once a summary reaches the bottom of the header above, it will stop there until the next section summary arrives.  Then, it will continue up the page.</p>

                            <p>The last summary will get pushed up the page by the footer once it undocks to reveal the content below it.</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

This is the javascript:

```
var summaries = $('.summary');
    summaries.each(function(i) {
        var summary = $(summaries[i]);
        var next = summaries[i + 1];

        summary.scrollToFixed({
            marginTop: $('.header').outerHeight(true) + 10,
            limit: function() {
                var limit = 0;
                if (next) {
                    limit = $(next).offset().top - $(this).outerHeight(true) - 10;
                } else {
                    limit = $('.footer').offset().top - $(this).outerHeight(true) - 10;
                }
                return limit;
            },
            zIndex: 999
        });
    });
```

If the number is sequential, it will run successfully. But if not, it didn't work at all. I know the wrong is in `var next = summaries[i + 1];` and then i replace it with `var next = summaries<?php echo $data['id_post']?>;` but it still not working.

The number **1** and **3** in summary **id** is my id_post. Does anyone know how to change var **next** with id_post?

Many thanks for the answer...

Comment: I thing, you next is not wrong. i is the actual index in the collection, so it started with 0, then 1, and so on... Let's `console.log(i);
   console.log(summary);
   console.log(next);` right after the `var next`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you can do this:

```
var summary = $(this);
var next = summary.next('.summary');
```

Give it a try and let me know if it helps.

Comment: i'm trying this 
`var summaries = $('.summary');
    summaries.each(function(i) {
        var summary = $(this);
        var next = summary.next('.summary');` but still did'nt work

Comment: What is the problem? Does it throw an error or something?

Comment: it didn't move when i scrolling down... The <ul summary> should be move down follow when i'am scrolling down.

Comment: Maybe you should change your if (next) to if (next.length > 0).

Comment: It helped? If not, post your code in JSFiddle, it'll be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
var next = $(this).next('.summary');
```